# Cannot import name 'imread', 'imresize', 'imsave' anaconda (windows)

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I am trying to import image to python but end up getting the same error again and again.

I have tried most of the solutions mentioned about this problem on multiple discussion threads but none of them have solved this issue of mine.
I have installed Pillow but still the error prevails. Would really appreciate some guidance on how to resolve this issue.

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize, imsave
import numpy as np
```

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c8bc16b68368> in <module>
----> 1 from scipy.misc import imread, imresize, imsave
      2 import numpy as np

ImportError: cannot import name 'imread'
```

Answer (score 3):

The library you're looking scipy.misc.imread is deprecated. You can use imageio. First install Pillow and then install imageio

```
pip install Pillow imageio
```

Then you can use,

```
imageio.imread('image1.png')
imageio.imread('image2.png', array)
```

But you cannot resize in imageio. Use numpy for that.

Answer (score 0):

What is your version? I think scipy.misc.imread is deprecated. Use imageio

```
    import imageio
    image = imageio.imread('pic.png')
```

Comment: python version 3.7.3

Comment: `import imageio` gives me another error saying 'No module name imageio'. I try installing matplotlib using `pip install matplotlib` but get 'Requirement already satisfied'

Comment: do `pip install imageio`